# How to Add "Icon" for a android App to open the app interface

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, project

Very New To Android.
Can somebody show me how to put a icon for the app..
can somebody tell me the steps to do so..?

Comment: [APP ICON](https://www.google.com) here it is

Answer (score 1):

- Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file
- Search for Application Tag.
- add icon option like "android:icon="@drawable/icon" in it.

See the following image,

> > [image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the `manifest.xml` file of your application.

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

This line will be there in application branch for icon. Change the drawable resource id there to the id of drawable folder image you want to keep as icon of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the ic_launcher png in res folder with yours.